# http download to disk with fsharp.data.dll and async workflows stalls

Tags: f#, f#-data

The following .fsx file is supposed to download and save to disk binary table base files which are posted as links in a html page on the internet, using `Fsharp.Data.dll`.

What happens, is that the whole thing stalls after a while and way before it is done, not even throwing an exception or alike.

I am pretty sure, I kind of mis-handle the `CopyToAsync()` thingy in my async workflow. As this is supposed to run while I go for a nap, it would be nice if someone could tell me how it is supposed to be done correctly. (In more general terms - how to handle a System.Threading.Task thingy in an async workflow thingy?)

```
#r @"E:\R\playground\DataTypeProviderStuff\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.3\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CommonExtensions
let document = HtmlDocument.Load("http://www.olympuschess.com/egtb/gaviota/")
let links = 
    document.Descendants ["a"] |> Seq.choose (fun x -> x.TryGetAttribute("href") |> Option.map (fun a -> a.Value()))
    |> Seq.filter (fun v -> v.EndsWith(".cp4"))
    |> List.ofSeq

let targetFolder = @"E:\temp\tablebases\"
let downloadUrls = 
    links |> List.map (fun name -> "http://www.olympuschess.com/egtb/gaviota/" + name, targetFolder + name )

let awaitTask = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore

let fetchAndSave (s,t) =
    async {
        printfn "Starting with %s..." s
        let! result = Http.AsyncRequestStream(s)
        use fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(t,System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        do! awaitTask (result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream))
        printfn "Done with %s." s
    }

let makeBatches n jobs =
    let rec collect i jl acc =
        match i,jl with
        | 0, _ -> acc,jl
        | _, [] -> acc,jl
        | _, x::xs -> collect (i-1) (xs) (acc @ [x])
    let rec loop remaining acc =
        match remaining with
        | [] -> acc
        | x::xs ->
            let r,rest = collect n remaining []
            loop rest (acc @ [r])
    loop jobs []


let download () = 
    downloadUrls 
    |> List.map fetchAndSave
    |> makeBatches 2
    |> List.iter (fun l -> l |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore )
    |> ignore

download()
```

**Note** Updated code so it creates batches of 2 downloads at a time and only the first batch works. Also added the awaitTask from the first answer as this seems the right way to do it.

**News** What is also funny: If I interrupt the stalled script and then #load it again into the same instance of fsi.exe, it stalls right away. I start to think it is a bug in the library I use or something like that.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: If anyone is still wondering about the 2 downloads only part. it has to do with the .Net ServicePointManager. By default it limits the number of connections to 2, but can be overridden with `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit <- 1000`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here fetchAndSave has been modified to handle the Task returned from CopyToAsync asynchronously. In your version you are waiting on the Task synchronously. Your script will appear to lock up as you are using Async.RunSynchronously to run the whole workflow. However the files do download as expected in the background.

```
let awaitTask = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore

let fetchAndSave (s,t) = async {
    let! result = Http.AsyncRequestStream(s)
    use fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(t,System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    do! awaitTask (result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream))
}
```

Of course you also need to call

```
do download()
```

on the last line of your script to kick things into motion.

Comment: While I think this is the correct answer, it still stalls for me after 2 files are done. Network traffic goes back to "zero" and no progress.

Comment: You may need to handle exceptions inside fetchAndSave.

Comment: if exceptions came, would it not result into some form of dump in fsi environment?

Comment: I changed the code now changing the many files for download in parallel into batches of only N downloads. Even there, only the first batch of 2 files works, the next batch never really "starts". I tried with the browser if the links work and they do. Browser starts to download... -> Updating my code in question accordingly.